# C# Newtonsoft Custom Serializer + ContractResolver not being called. [ElasticSearch]

Tags: c#, entity-framework, elasticsearch, json.net

This error occurs when serializing some EntityFramework models in order to send them to ElasticSearch.

I'm using a custom serializer + custom contract resolver derived from those classes: `ConnectionSettingsAwareSerializerBase` + `DefaultContractResolver`.

I did this in order to exclude virtual properties from being serialized, because I'm trying to get rid of the self-referencing problem when serializing EntityFramework models with relationships between them.

I think the problem is that the `DefaultContractResolver@CreateProperty()` method is not called correctly.

This is how I instanciate my ElasticSearch client:

```
private static ElasticClient CreateESClient()
{
    Uri ElasticSearchUri = new Uri(ElasticSearchConnectionString);
    var connSettings = new ConnectionSettings(
        new  SingleNodeConnectionPool(ElasticSearchUri),
        (builtin, settings) => new CustomSerializer(builtin, settings)
    );
    connSettings.DefaultIndex("my_index");

    var client = new ElasticClient(connSettings);

    return client;
}
```

I created these classes:
`CustomSerializer : ConnectionSettingsAwareSerializerBase` - where I set a custom ContractResolver (this is executed and breakpoints are hit)

```
internal class CustomSerializer : ConnectionSettingsAwareSerializerBase
{
    public CustomSerializer(IElasticsearchSerializer builtinSerializer, IConnectionSettingsValues connectionSettings)
        : base(builtinSerializer, connectionSettings)   
    {
        //
    }

    protected override JsonSerializerSettings CreateJsonSerializerSettings() =>
        new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new ExcludeVirtualPropertiesResolver()
        };
}
```

The contract resolver: `ExcludeVirtualPropertiesResolver : DefaultContractResolver` (breakpoints not being hit)

```
internal class ExcludeVirtualPropertiesResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty prop = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        // added for debugging, should not serialize any property
        prop.ShouldSerialize = obj => false;

        //if (member is PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
        //{
        //    if (propertyInfo.GetGetMethod()?.IsVirtual ?? false)
        //    {
        //        prop.ShouldSerialize = obj => false;
        //    }
        //}

        return prop;
    }
}
```

I have added some breakpoints to see if the `CreateProperty` method is called, but they are not being hit. Also the properties are being serialized and an exception is thrown.

Do you know what the problem might be? Is this the wrong solution for my self-referencing while serializing problem?

Comment: If you check the [source code for `ConnectionSettingsAwareSerializerBase`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/main/src/Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch.JsonNetSerializer/ConnectionSettingsAwareSerializerBase.Serializer.cs#L59), you will see a method [`protected virtual ConnectionSettingsAwareContractResolver CreateContractResolver()`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/main/src/Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch.JsonNetSerializer/ConnectionSettingsAwareSerializerBase.Serializer.cs#L66C2-L66C84) is called which returns a contract resolver that overwrites your resolver.

Comment: Try subclassing [`ConnectionSettingsAwareContractResolver`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/main/src/Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch.JsonNetSerializer/ConnectionSettingsAwareContractResolver.cs) and overriding `ConnectionSettingsAwareSerializer.CreateContractResolver()`, it should probably do what you want.

Comment: Also, what version of `Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch` are you using?

Comment: I'll try doing what you suggested, thanks!

I'm using Elasticsearch.Net v7.17.5

Comment: I subclassed the `ConnectionSettingsAwareContractResolver` and it works now, thank you!